# Sentence meaning simple present tense

Tags: sentence-construction

I am unable to understand meaning of below sentense .

Does this sentence indicates both the events i.e. effect of poison and writhing were simultaneously happening

> a) For six hours, 20-year-old Sushma writhed in agony on the floor as the poison did its work.

Hense my Versoin is

> b) For six hours, 20-year-old Sushma was writhing in agony on the floor as the poison had done its work.

This is because it was  effect of poison which made her writhed on floor. So first action would be effect of poison and later writhing.

Comment: In general "X as Y" means "at the same time".  So yes, the poison was taking effect *at the same time* as she was writhing.

Comment: If the poison had done its work, then why is Sushma writhing. She would either be dead or recovered.

Answer (score 2):

*Did* in the context of an *as* or *while* clause is non-perfective: that is, it implies a continuous activity rather than a completed action.

In this case, the poison is "doing its work" throughout the six-hour period: it is continuously causing her to writhe in agony.